# Amazon S3 as like local files from php and html

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know there's SDK to handle s3 files like uploading and downloading, AND I know s3 files can be accessed by unique url.

HOWEVER,
I'd like to know that there's the best easiest way to access files from PHP script and html script like accessing to local files.

```
//Example for html -
<img src='/image/1.jpg'>
```

for this case, I need to change all the url from '/image/1.jpg' to s3 urls.

```
//Example for php -
$file = 'assets/jquery.js';
echo '<script src='.$file.'></script>';
```

The only way to access to s3 is that I have to change all local files access relative codes from local directory and file to s3 urls?

Changing all full or absolute file path to be s3 url is not a good way.
But is this only way to do so??

What about S3FU? 
It's not recommended but works properly as other say.
Only reading files using S3FU and uploading SDK? what do you think?

Comment: There is a **reasonj* it is not recommended.  The same is true for any filesystem emulation, like s3fs-fuse.  Don't do it.  Is your path space clean and well-organized?  That is, is everything in `/image/` and `/assets/` going to be stored in S3?  If so, you could use CloudFront to automatically route those requests to the bucket and send all other paths to your application, with no application changes.

Comment: ...although both examples you provide are actually examples of links in HTML.  In the second example, it's HTML rendered by PHP, but the fact that PHP is involved isn't significant.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It would be better if you wrote those replies as an answer :(
Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes, I agree... but I was attempting to gauge your interest in the solution before I posted it, with some additonal detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have S3 compatible bucket you can always use [CloudBerry](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/explorer/amazon-s3.aspx) for keeping the same *"folder structure"*

Then only thing you need to do is to prepend all paths with proper domain.
Does it solve your problem?

Comment: *"Then only thing you need to do is to prepend all paths with proper domain."*  That's what OP seems to be trying to avoid.